# What is the difference between these two ways to compare STL vectors?

Tags: c++, std

Few examples available online use the equality operator to compare the contents of two STL `vector` objects in order to verify that they have the same content.

```
vector<T> v1;
// add some elements to v1

vector<T> v2;
// add some elements to v2

if (v1 == v2) cout << "v1 and v2 have the same content" << endl;
else cout << "v1 and v2 are different" << endl;
```

Instead, I read other examples where the [`std::equal()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/) function is used.

```
bool compare_vector(const vector<T>& v1, const vector<T>& v2)
{
    return v1.size() == v2.size()
           && std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());
}
```

What is the difference between these two ways to compare STL vectors?

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two behave in exactly the same way. The container requirements (Table 96) say that `a == b` has the operational semantics of:

```
distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(b.begin(), b.end()) &&
equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())
```

Comment: Kerrek SB, what is Table 96?

Comment: How is the equal operator defined?  IOW, why not use size() instead of distance?

Comment: @RyanGuthrie: "operational semantics". Everything is probably inlined anyway, and `size()` is usually computed as a difference. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @AStidham: The 96th table in the C++11 standard, entitled "Container requirements".

Answer (score 5):

Good question. I suspect that people don't use `==` because they don't know its there, but it does exactly what the hand-coded version does. It's always been there for sequence containers and for associative containers.

Comment: Is this the same for vectors in c++03

Comment: @Ben - yes, it's always been the case. And I mis-remembered in my original answer; associative containers have always had `==` (and `!=`) as well.